The Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) Pair of Rectangular / Indicator Function
I'm trying to properly understand the fft and tired to recover the sinc function from its Fourier transform, i.e. an indicator function. What it the issue with the python code below? Why does psi not coincide with sinc?
Thanks in advance!
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def indicator(w):
    y = np.zeros_like(x, dtype="complex")
    y[abs(w)<1] = 1
    return y

N = 500

a = 4
x = np.linspace(-a, a, N, endpoint=False)
dx = 2*a/N

w = np.fft.fftfreq(N, d=dx)
psi = indicator(w)
psi = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(psi)) 
psi /= np.max(np.abs(psi)) # rescale for plotting

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.plot(x, psi)
plt.plot(x, np.sinc(x))


I can't say as to why, but if you multiply x in np.sinc(x) by sqrt(pi), then it matches much better.

Yes, I also think that it has something to do with values of x and w but I can't figure it out...

@Sim: a) why do you expect a sinc(). For a discrete system I would expect a Dirichlet kernel. b) there isn't a single comment in your code and it's hard to read or follow. c) you have a time scale error. I think it should be plt.plot(x, np.sinc(6/np.pi*x)). d) I suggest walking through the math on paper first and then coding it up. You can compare the math against the code one step at a time, which helps with debugging.

It will be easier to work on a time domain signal and analyze its DFT. Yet it will be similar the other way around.
We can define the discrete rectangular of length $N$ function in 2 manners:

Symmetric: $x \left[ n \right] = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } \left| n \right| \leq W \\ 0 & \text{ if } \left| n \right| > W \end{cases}, \; n = -M, -M + 1, \ldots, 0, 1, \ldots, M, \; N = 2 M + 1$.
Non Symmetric: $x \left[ n \right] = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } n \leq W \\ 0 & \text{ if } n > W \end{cases}, \; n = 0, 1, \ldots, N - 1$.

Then, their DFT transform is given by a variation of the Dirichlet Kernel:

Symmetric: $X \left[ k \right] = \begin{cases} \frac{ \sin \left( \pi \left( 2 W + 1 \right) \frac{k}{N} \right) }{ \sin \left( \pi \frac{k}{N} \right) } & \text{ if } k \neq 0 \\ 2W + 1 & \text{ if } k = 0 \end{cases}, \; k = 0, 1, \ldots, N - 1$.
Non Symmetric: $X \left[ k \right] = \begin{cases} \exp \left( -j \frac{2 \pi k}{N} \frac{W}{2} \right) \frac{ \sin \left( \pi \left( W + 1 \right) \frac{k}{N} \right) }{ \sin \left( \pi \frac{k}{N} \right) } & \text{ if } k \neq 0 \\ W + 1 & \text{ if } k = 0 \end{cases}, \; k = 0, 1, \ldots, N - 1$.

In Python it will be something like:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def DirichletKernel( N: int, W: float, symFlag: bool = True ):
    # The complex phase shift is neglected for the non symmetric case
        
    vD = np.zeros(shape = N)
    if symFlag:
        WW = 2 * W + 1
    else:
        WW = W + 1
    for kk in range(1, numSamples):
        kn = kk / N
        vD[kk] = np.sin(np.pi * WW * kn) / np.sin(np.pi * kn)

        vD[kk] = np.sin(np.pi * WW * kn) / np.sin(np.pi * kn)
    
    vD[0] = WW

    return vD

symFlag = True

dataRadius = 5
numSamples = 2 * dataRadius + 1
if symFlag:
    vX = np.linspace(-dataRadius, dataRadius, 2 * dataRadius + 1, dtype = np.int_)
else:
    vX = np.linspace(0, 2 * dataRadius, 2 * dataRadius + 1, dtype = np.int_)

# Window Size
W = 2

vY = np.zeros(shape = numSamples)
vY[np.abs(vX) <= W] = 1.0


vK = np.abs(np.fft.fft(vY))
vF = np.fft.fftfreq(numSamples)

vD = DirichletKernel(numSamples, W, symFlag = symFlag)

hF, hA = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 6))
hA.scatter(vF, vK, label = 'DFT')
hA.scatter(vF, np.abs(vD), label = 'Dirichlet')
hA.legend();


As can be seen, they match perfectly.
They will match for $W = 0$ as well, which is the discrete indicator function (Dirac Delta Function).
In this case, the DFT is constant.
Remark: In the code, I neglected the complex phase shift as it makes no difference for the magnitude.
